# How to align two equations vertically without horizontal space?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, align

Please have a look at the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath,amstext,amssymb}
\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\cdots\text{ABB}&\bigg|\text{BAABB}&\bigg|\text{AAABB}&\bigg|\text{BB}&\bigg|\text{BB}&\bigg|\text{ABABAABABB}&\bigg|\text{AA}\cdots \\
n_0 &  n_1 & n_2 & n_3 & n_4 & n_5
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

This produces the following output:

[image]

I want to align the vertical lines `$\bigg|$` and the corresponding labels `$n_i$` below each other. I do not want to have the additional white space after the `$\bigg|$` in equation (1) either. How can I achieve that?

Comment: A simple solution is to insert a negative thin space: `\bigg|\!`

Comment: @Marco Daniel Negative thin space only removes the white space after every second $\bigg|$ somehow ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution, if I've well understood what you want. It's based on the code for the `\vdotswithin` command from `mathtools`. So I define a `\vertwithin{label}` command, which puts the  `\vert` command  centred in a box of width the labelwidth, and uses this box as alignment point.

B.t.w., for n alignment points, you need `2n-1` ampersands. Also, you don't have to load `mathtext` if you load `amsmath` (nor if you load `mathtools`, which loads amsmath)

I'm not sure whether you want white space at the end of text segments, so I provided both solutions:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}

\newcommand\vertwithin[1]{%
{\mathmakebox[\widthof{\ensuremath{{}#1{}}}][c]{{\biggm\vert}}}}%

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
 ⋯ \text{ABB} & \vertwithin{n₀} \text{BAABB} & & \vertwithin{n₁} \text{AAABB}& &\vertwithin{n₂} \text{BB} & & \vertwithin{n₃} \text{BB} & & \vertwithin{n₄} \text{ABABAABABB} & & \vertwithin{n₅} \text{AA} ⋯ \\
 & n₀ & & n₁ & & n₂ & & n₃ & & n₄ & & n₅
\end{align}

\begin{alignat}{6}
 ⋯ \text{ABB} & \vertwithin{n₀} \text{BAABB} & & \vertwithin{n₁} \text{AAABB}& & \vertwithin{n₂} \text{BB} & & \vertwithin{n₃} \text{BB} & & \vertwithin{n₄} \text{ABABAABABB} & & \vertwithin{n₅} \text{AA} ⋯ \\
 & n₀ & & n₁ & & n₂ & & n₃ & & n₄ & & n₅
\end{alignat}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can use `alignat` to remove the gaps between the alignment marks `&`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools,eqparbox}

\begin{document}

% Original alignment
\begin{align}
  \cdots\text{ABB}&\bigg|\text{BAABB}&\bigg|\text{AAABB}&\bigg|\text{BB}&\bigg|\text{BB}&\bigg|\text{ABABAABABB}&\bigg|\text{AA}\cdots \\
  n_0 &  n_1 & n_2 & n_3 & n_4 & n_5
\end{align}

% Updated alignment
\newcommand{\setvert}{\eqmakebox[eqmb]{$\bigg|$}}
\newcommand{\setsub}[1]{\eqmakebox[eqmb]{$\mathclap{#1}$}}
\begin{alignat}{6}
  \cdots\text{ABB}
    &\setvert\text{BAABB}
    &&\setvert\text{AAABB}
    &&\setvert\text{BB}
    &&\setvert\text{BB}
    &&\setvert\text{ABABAABABB}
    &&\setvert\text{AA}
  \cdots \\
    &\setsub{n_0}
    &&\setsub{n_1}
    &&\setsub{n_2}
    &&\setsub{n_3}
    &&\setsub{n_4}
    &&\setsub{n_5}
\end{alignat}

\end{document}
```

[`eqparbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/eqparbox)'s `\eqmakebox[<tag>]{<stuff>}` figures out the width of `<stuff>` across all similar `<tag>`s (so needs at least two compilations on the first go). I placed the enumerations in the second equation inside a `\mathclap` to avoid it influencing the `alignat` alignment.

Comment: Initially I also had thought of a solution like this. Note it works only because  all labels have more or less the same width

Comment: @Bernard: I've removed the width of the labels with `\mathclap`, using only the width of `\bigg|`.

Comment: I hadn't noticed. That's a nice idea!